# How to limit Pagination with Search from Mysqli on this code php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, pagination

i tried 2 month for this code i try modify output limit pagination
but not work for me every time

```
<?php
                        ini_set( 'display_errors', 1 );
                        error_reporting( ~0 );

                        $strKeyword = null;

                        if ( isset( $_POST["txtKeyword"] ) ) {
                            $strKeyword = $_POST["txtKeyword"];
                        }
                        if ( isset( $_GET["txtKeyword"] ) ) {
                            $strKeyword = $_GET["txtKeyword"];
                        }
                        ?>

 include( 'condb.php' );
                            $sql      = "SELECT *FROM an_files WHERE (f_episode LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%' or f_name LIKE '%" . $strKeyword . "%')";
                            $query    = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
                            $num_rows = mysqli_num_rows( $query );
                            $per_page = 5;   // Per Page
                            $page     = 1;

                            if ( isset( $_GET["Page"] ) ) {
                                $page = $_GET["Page"];
                            }

                            $prev_page = $page - 1;
                            $next_page = $page + 1;

                            $row_start = ( ( $per_page * $page ) - $per_page );
                            if ( $num_rows <= $per_page ) {
                                $num_pages = 1;
                            } else if ( ( $num_rows % $per_page ) == 0 ) {
                                $num_pages = ( $num_rows / $per_page );
                            } else {
                                $num_pages = ( $num_rows / $per_page ) + 1;
                                $num_pages = (int) $num_pages;
                            }
                            $row_end = $per_page * $page;
                            if ( $row_end > $num_rows ) {
                                $row_end = $num_rows;
                            }

                            $sql   .= "ORDER BY f_date DESC LIMIT $row_start ,4 ";
                            $query = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

             <form class="form-search" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>" method="post">
                                <table border="0" align="right" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="border: hidden; text-align: right">
                                            <input placeholder="Searth" type="text"
                                                   class="input-medium search-query" name="txtKeyword" id="txtKeyword">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </form>

  <div class="pagination">

                                            <?php
                                            if ( $prev_page ) {
                                                echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$prev_page&txtKeyword=$strKeyword'><< Back</a> ";
                                            }

                                            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $num_pages; $i ++ ) {
                                                if ( $i != $page ) {
                                                    echo "<a  href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$i&txtKeyword=$strKeyword'>$i</a> ";
                                                } else {
                                                    echo "<a class='active'><b> $i  </b></a>";
                                                }
                                            }


                                            if ( $page != $num_pages ) {
                                                echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$next_page&txtKeyword=$strKeyword'>Next>></a> ";
                                            }
                                            ?>
                                        </div>
```

this out out 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

i want out put 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10...20

how can i modify this code thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a combination of MySQL's `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`. I see you are using `LIMIT`, but without `OFFSET`, you'll continue to get the same results.

Here's a simple article to get the idea: [LIMIT and OFFSET SQL Pagination](https://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm)

Pretend you have 1000 records in your `an_files` table, which you want to show 25 at a time per page. Your query should become something like this:

```
"SELECT * FROM an_files 
WHERE
  f_episode LIKE '%mykeyword%'
  OR
  f_name LIKE '%anotherkeyword%'
ORDER BY f_date DESC
LIMIT " . $per_page . " " .
"OFFSET " . (0 * ($page_num - 1))
```

Now, all you have to do is pass the `$per_page` amount to PHP as well as the $page_num (page number). We substract `1` from the page number because we usually don't "zero-index" page numbers in real life, so when a user clicks on the link to page 1, and you send `$page_num = 1` to the backend, 
without subtracting you will offset by one record, so you will never get that first record, hence subtract the page number by 1.

So if I wanted to see results from page 6, for example, the query you end up translating to:

```
SELECT * FROM an_files 
WHERE
  f_episode LIKE '%mykeyword%'
  OR
  f_name LIKE '%anotherkeyword%'
ORDER BY f_date DESC
LIMIT 25
OFFSET 125
```

which will show the next 25 records *after* the first 125 records produced by `SELECT * FROM an_files WHERE f_episode LIKE '%mykeyword%' OR f_name LIKE '%anotherkeyword%' ORDER BY f_date DESC`

- 1-25: 1st page
- 26-50: 2nd page
- 51-75: 3rd page
- 76-100: 4th page
- 101-125: 5th page
- **126-150: 6th page**
- etc

Now, if you want to generate a total count of all records so you can generate your pagination links, I would suggest doing a separate new query to return you the number of records for the base query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM an_files WHERE f_episode LIKE '%mykeyword%' OR f_name LIKE '%anotherkeyword%';
```

So in this case, if you have 1000 records in your `an_files` table, the result should be `1000`.

Comment: can you show full modify this code ? i really don't know it's hard to work